# Event handler in constructor behaves differently than event handler out of constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I have two instances of an object that extends `EventEmitter` and listens to an event called `finish`. If I set the event handler outside the constructor everything works as expected. Each instance hears the occurence of `finish` that it triggers. But if I set the event handler inside the constructor, only the instance created second hears and reacts to the event, or so it seems.

Here is the code:

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var fs = require('fs');

var NEXT_ID = 0;
var MyEmitter = function() {
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.id = NEXT_ID;
  NEXT_ID++;
  console.log('CREATED EMITTER WITH ID:', this.id)
  self = this;
  this.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('FINISH EVENT . CONSTRUCTOR LISTENER .', 
                'LISTENER ID:', self.id, 
                '. ORIGINATOR ID:', this.id);
  });
};

util.inherits(MyEmitter, EventEmitter);

var setFinishListener = function(emitter) {
  emitter.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('FINISH EVENT . NON-CONSTRUCTOR LISTENER .', 
                'LISTENER ID:', emitter.id, 
                '. ORIGINATOR ID:', this.id);
  });
}

var emitter0 = new MyEmitter();
var emitter1 = new MyEmitter(); 

setFinishListener(emitter0);
setFinishListener(emitter1);

emitter0.emit('finish');
emitter1.emit('finish');

// The following is logged to the console:
// FINISH EVENT . CONSTRUCTOR LISTENER . LISTENER ID: 1 . ORIGINATOR ID: 0
// FINISH EVENT . NON-CONSTRUCTOR LISTENER . LISTENER ID: 0 . ORIGINATOR ID: 0
// FINISH EVENT . CONSTRUCTOR LISTENER . LISTENER ID: 1 . ORIGINATOR ID: 1
// FINISH EVENT . NON-CONSTRUCTOR LISTENER . LISTENER ID: 1 . ORIGINATOR ID: 1
```

Notice that the `LISTENER ID` for the version of the event handler that  is set up within the constructor of `MyEmitter` always belongs to the second created instance, making it seem that that instance is always catching the event first, and for some reason the first created instance never has that handler triggered.

Two facts that I am assuming I understand correctly:

1. `this` in the event handler should always be the object that emitted the event.
2. `this` in the constructor should always be the object to be returned by the constructor (because it is called with `new`).

If both of these are true I don't know what else I am not understanding that results in the exhibited behavior.

One other thing this made me think about: Should an event always be "heard" by the same EventEmitter that emitted the event? That is what I thought and certainly that seems to be the most common use case. But if that is not a restriction then how, for example, does a `click` event on a button not trigger the click handlers for all the other buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you are not using `var self = this;` to pin the `self` variable to the Emitters scope. When you leave the `var` out, Javascript will hoist the variable up in scope until it finds a matching variable name declared with `var`. Since you never declared one, `self` will be hosted up all the way to the global scope, and thus each emitter will get created with the same reference.

Adding `var self = this` will solve the problem. You can also add `use strict` to catch these kinds of issues, as it will not allow you to declare a variable without using `var`.

Comment: Can't believe how silly I was to miss that. Was trying to fix this in someone's old code and was looking way too deep. Completely missed the lack of var in front of self. Thanks!